# Install exp/html in Go

Tags: installation, go

It looks like Go doesn't support HTML web parsing tools/packages yet, despite it already providing XML scraping via `encoding/xml`. So how can I install `exp/html` package in Go?

As far as I know, all the answers, at least I stumbled upon on the Web with 10 minutes worth of searching, didn't return the correct answer; when I tried to run those, I got the error `cannot find package XXX in YYY` or `no Go source files in XXX`.

So as of now, can I install it without re-compling and setting the whole Go environment from scratch? Or am I missing something?

I'm on OS X 10.8 and run Go version 1.1, which I installed from OS X package installer.

For your information, these code didn't make it.

```
go get code.google.com/p/go/src/pkg/exp/html
go get code.google.com/p/go.exp/inotify
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the html package available as just `html` now?  Presumably it was only in the experimental directory when its API wasn't as stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried:

```
go get code.google.com/p/go.net/html
```

and it seemed to work.

I have a feeling it's been moved from the `exp` library to the new `net` library.

EDIT: [Documentation](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html) & [browseable repo](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/?repo=net#hg%2Fhtml).

Comment: See [VonC's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26773535/55504) for the current location (code.google.com is shutting down).

Answer (score 1):

With go 1.4 (November 9th, 2014), you will have to type:

```
go get golang.org/x/net/html
```

See:

- "[New Import paths for Go sub-repositories](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-announce/eD8dh3T9yyA)".
- "[Go 1.4 subrepo renaming](http://golang.org/s/go14subrepo)".